# Test class for sending email with Attachment

Tags: unit-test, apex-email-service

I need a test class for sending a email

```
public blob body;   
        public PageReference pdfmethod(){
        try
        {
         // to get mail id
         Opportunity_Potential__c opp= [Select id,Account__r.Name,Account__r.Con_Email__pc,Account__r.Con_Email1__pc,Account__r.Con_Email2__pc from Opportunity_Potential__c where id=:qp];
         System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+opp);
         Set<id> ac= new Set<id>();

         String emailid=opp.Account__r.Con_Email__pc;

         String email1id=opp.Account__r.Con_Email1__pc;
         PageReference ref=page.Rent_Resell;
         body=ref.getContentAsPDF();

         Messaging.EmailFileAttachment mefa=new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
         mefa.setContentType('application/pdf');
         mefa.setFileName('Property Recommendation');
         mefa.Body=body;

         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msem=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
         msem.setToAddresses(new String[] {+emailid});
         msem.setSubject('VINTAGE PROPERTY RECOMMENDATION');
         msem.setHtmlBody('<p><font><span style="color:#535664"><b>Dear Sir/Madam,</b></span></font></p><p><font><span style="color:#535664">Greetings from <b>Vintage!</b></span></font></p> <p><font><span style="color:#535664">This is further to your enquiry for Property Search services with our company. Please find alongwith some of the property options that is Available with us & which may suit your requirement. Request you to review the same and get back to us for any clarification or assistance.</span></font></p><p><font><span style="color:#535664">It would be our endeavor to help you get a suitable property at the earliest. We hope you would give us active support to us in order to render Quality & Professional service.</span></font></p>');
         msem.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {mefa});
         //send email
         Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {msem});

         // Edited code starts here
         if(email1id != null)
         {
         Messaging.EmailFileAttachment mefa1=new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
         mefa1.setContentType('application/pdf');
         mefa1.setFileName('Property Recommendation');
         mefa1.Body=body;

         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msem1=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
         msem1.setToAddresses(new String[] {+email1id});
         msem1.setSubject('VINTAGE PROPERTY RECOMMENDATION');
         msem1.setHtmlBody('<p><font><span style="color:#535664"><b>Dear Sir/Madam,</b></span></font></p><p><font><span style="color:#535664">Greetings from <b>Vintage!</b></span></font></p> <p><font><span style="color:#535664">This is further to your enquiry for Property Search services with our company. Please find alongwith some of the property options that is Available with us & which may suit your requirement. Request you to review the same and get back to us for any clarification or assistance.</span></font></p><p><font><span style="color:#535664">It would be our endeavor to help you get a suitable property at the earliest. We hope you would give us active support to us in order to render Quality & Professional service.</span></font></p>');
         msem1.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {mefa1});
         //send email
         Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {msem1});

         }

         // Edited code ends here 

        List<Apartments__c> ap=new List<Apartments__c>();
         ap=[select id from Apartments__c where id in:ids];
         System.debug('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'+ids);

         for(Apartments__c cw: ap){
          Recommendation__c r=new Recommendation__c();
         r.Apartment_Name__c=cw.id;
         //jaba
         r.Opportunity_Potential__c=qp;
         insert r;
       }
       System.debug('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'+selectedCategories);
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM, 'Success!  Email has been sent to customer Email Id:'+emailid , +email1id ));
         }catch(Exception ex){

         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error'+ex));
        }
```

i should get 100% code coverage when i write this in my test class

```
classname cn=new classname();
cn.pdfmethod();
```

method is passing but i'm not getting code coverage,

And how to write test class for email with pdf attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use

```
getContentAsPDF
```

In Test.

The only way is to use Test.isRunningTest():

```
if (!Test.isRunningTest()){
    body = thePage.getContentAsPDF(); 
}
else{
    body = Blob.valueof('Some random String');
}
```